# How do I properly fail an async unit test in jasmine-node

Tags: node.js, jasmine-node

Why does the following code fail with a timeout? It looks like 'should' throws an error and done() never gets called? How do I write this test so that it fails correctly instead of having jasmine reporting a timeout?

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var should = require('chai').should();
describe('test', function () {
  it('should work', function (done) {
    Promise.resolve(3)
      .then(function (num) {
        num.should.equal(4);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

console output is:

c:>jasmine-node spec\

Unhandled rejection AssertionError: expected 3 to equal 4
...
Failures:
1) test should work
Message:
timeout: timed out after 5000 msec waiting for spec to complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `Promises` in your `Mocha` suite, you have to `return` it instead of using the `done()` callback, like:

```
describe('test', function () {
  it('should work', function () {
    return Promise.resolve(3)
      .then(function (num) {
        num.should.equal(4);
      });
  });
});
```

An even cleaner way to write that would be with [`chai-as-promised`](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/) module:

```
describe('test', function () {
  it('should work', function () {
    return Promise.resolve(3).should.eventually.equal(4);
  });
});
```

Just make sure to require it properly and tell `chai` to use it:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var chai = require('chai');
var should = chai.should();
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip to use chai-as-promised. Using jasmine-node, I had to  do `return Promise.resolve(3).should.eventually.equal(4).and.notify(done);`

Comment: Oh, sorry, just now I saw that you were talking about `jasmine`, not `mocha`. But yeah, `chai-as-promised` supports `jasmine` too. And other thing: I'm quite sure recent versions of `jasmine` already supports node by default, so you don't need `jasmine-node` unless you don't want to migrate to a newer version.

Answer (score 5):

### Using `.then()` and only `done()`

```
it('should work', (done) => {
  Promise.resolve(3).then((num) => {
    // your assertions here
  }).catch((err) => {
    expect(err).toBeFalsy();
  }).then(done);
});
```

### Using `.then()` and `done.fail()`

```
it('should work', (done) => {
  Promise.resolve(3).then((num) => {
    // your assertions here
  }).then(done).catch(done.fail);
});
```

### Using Bluebird coroutines

```
it('should work', (done) => {
  Promise.coroutine(function *g() {
    let num = yield Promise.resolve(3);
    // your assertions here
  })().then(done).catch(done.fail);
});
```

### Using `async`/`await`

```
it('should work', async (done) => {
  try {
    let num = await Promise.resolve(3);
    // your assertions here
    done();
  } catch (err) {
    done.fail(err);
  }
});
```

### Using `async`/`await` with `.catch()`

```
it('should work', (done) => {
  (async () => {
    let num = await Promise.resolve(3);
    // your assertions here
    done();
  })().catch(done.fail);
});
```

### Other options

You specifically asked about `jasmine-node` so that's what the above examples are about but there are also other modules that let you directly return promises from tests instead of calling `done()` and `done.fail()` - see:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-promises
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-as-promised
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-promise-matchers
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-then